# Everytime I stop the WebLogic Server, the compiled JSP files are removed. Did I do something wrong?

Tags: weblogic

When I start the managed server, I can see some newly complied JSPs. e.g. $DOME_MAIN/servers//tmp/_WL_user//dytjca/jsp_servlet/__foo.class

When I stop the managed server, the file was deleted!
When I start the managed server, the file was re-created again.
Why was that? Did I misconfigure something?

My weblogic.xml looks like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wls:weblogic-web-app xmlns:wls="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.3/weblogic-web-app.xsd">
    <wls:weblogic-version>10.3.6</wls:weblogic-version>
    <wls:context-root>poc</wls:context-root>
    <wls:jsp-descriptor>
        <wls:precompile>true</wls:precompile>
        <wls:precompile-continue>true</wls:precompile-continue>
    </wls:jsp-descriptor>
</wls:weblogic-web-app>
```

Regards,
nww

Comment: Just found that it is a bug in WebLogic. I applied the patch. Now, the compiled JSP will not be deleted when managed server stop. But, it comes a bigger problem. The compiled JSP will not be recompiled even the corresponding JSP is updated in the war file!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. Don't simply update your war file by file copy. Using WLST script solves the mystery. Thanks.